# Using HTML.RoutLink to add onto the existing url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to use HTML.RouteLink() to add onto the existing url. For example I have

```
<%: Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues) %>
```

My controller is Pages, and my action is somestring. So the generated url would be

**localhost/Page/somestring**

This is fine. However I would link the generated url when I visit http://localhost:1241/Admin/ section to be

**localhost/Admin/Page/somestring**

Instead of

**localhost/Page/somestring**

This **localhost/Page/somestring** url is setup in my global.asx file to route to  view a page, and the **localhost/Admin/Page/somestring** url is routed to edit the page.

I hope this is making sense and thank you all for your help!

Tyrone

Here Are my two routes which could give you some idea

---

```
routes.MapRoute(null,"Pages/{page}", new { controller = "Pages", action = "Page" });

routes.MapRoute("Edit Pages", "Admin/Page/{page}",new { controller = "Admin", action = "EditPage", id =UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: What `Admin` section are you talking about? How is this set in your global.asax? Are you using areas?

Comment: For Example I will login to my admin section and be redirected to a url localhost/Admin. I am using the same navigation partial view in my admin section as I am using in my frontend section.I edited my Post above.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough information to answer this question thoroughly. As I understand it, you have a partial that uses the same code whether you're in the admin or not to generate the URL. But you want the same code to generate different URLs depending on whether you're in the admin or not.

The trick here is that you need the route values to match the defaults of the route you want to match.

In this case, to link to the non-admin:

```
Html.RouteLink(linkText, new {controller="Pages", action="Page", page = thePage})
```

But to link to the admin version

```
Html.RouteLink(linkText, new {controller="Admin", action="EditPage", page = thePage})
```

So what you need to do is make sure the partial gets the right values depending on which context it's being used in.

Comment: what about making your own version of the RouteLink-method and inside make a check for IsAuthenticated (which i guess tells you if your in admin or not) and internally call RouteLink with the correct value for Controller (pages or admin)